# Powershell select A string and After a word

Tags: powershell

My question Is there a way to select **Virtualname** with select-string? I have these logs from where I need to select the time and virtual account name. I

```
*>   <event seq="453211" time="2019-01-24 11:01:03.639873 -0500" app="hServer 7.45" name="I_SFS_TRANSFER_FILE" desc="Virtual filesystem: transfer file.">
      <session id="44500" service="SSH" remoteAddress="00.00.00:57292" virtualAccount="xxxxxxxx" windowsAccount="Server3\Users"/>
      <channel type="session" id="1"/>
      <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="90000" desc="Transferring file ended.">*
```

This is what I tried so far.

```
New-Item "C:\clients.log" -type file -force
$strings = "virtualAccount=","time="
Foreach($string in $strings){
Get-Content 'C:\uploads.log'| 
Select-String $string1 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }  |
Add-Content "C:\clients.log"
}
```

Comment: Are there one or more virtualAccount and time fields per logfile? If there are more per file: Is the info as shown on one line or including the line breaks like your example?

Comment: There are more, its just one line I copied

Comment: You should show what results you do expect.

Answer (score 0):

If your code gave the data wanted, my guess is that it was not in the order you want it. I assume want to have the timestamps and account names together and not a separate bunch of timestamps, followed by the account names. I wrote the example below that creates a $myInfo object containing the info you want from the log lines. I hope it helps to write your solution.

I have to say the regex's are not mine. I had a hard time capturing the text between the quotes. Google helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content 'C:\uploads.log') {
    $rslt = $line | Select-String -Pattern 'time=\"([^\"]*)\".*virtualAccount=\"([^\"]*)\"'
    $myinfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Time = $rslt.Matches.Groups[1].Value;
        Account = $rslt.Matches.Groups[2].Value
    }
    $myinfo
}
```

Comment: No luck error `Cannot index into a null array.
At line:3 char:5
+     [PSCustomObject]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:3 char:5
+     [PSCustomObject]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 `

Comment: Probably not every line in the log contains the strings searched. If that is the case you should add a check on that or add a try-catch

Comment: Yeah got, I will need to copy all in one line, thats gona be tough work

Answer (score 0):

This is the method to split the string with a word you can do what you need

```
$str = '<event seq="453211" time="2019-01-24 11:01:03.639873 -0500" app="hServer 7.45" name="I_SFS_TRANSFER_FILE" desc="Virtual filesystem: transfer file.">
          <session id="44500" service="SSH" remoteAddress="00.00.00:57292" virtualAccount="xxxxxxxx" windowsAccount="Server3\Users"/>
          <channel type="session" id="1"/>
          <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="90000" desc="Transferring file ended.">*'
    
    $str2= $str -split ('time=') -split ('app=') -split ('name=') -split ('desc=') -split ('id=') -split ('service=') -split ('remoteAddress=')-split ('virtualAccount=')-split ('windowsAccount=') -split ('channel type=') 
    
    Write-host "time=" $str2[1]
    Write-host "app=" $str2[2]
    Write-host "name=" $str2[3]
    Write-host "desc="$str2[4]
    Write-host "id="$str2[5]
    Write-host "service= "$str2[6]
    Write-host "remoteAddress= "$str2[7]
    Write-host "virtualAccount= "$str2[8]
    Write-host "windowsAccount=" $str2[9]
```